# ogr2ogr command : chaining -clipsrc and -sql filters?

Tags: sql, ogr2ogr

I'am currently doing a clip then SQL query to select the biggest cities out of Natural Earth data via 2 commands :

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrc 1 52 7 49 ./tmp.shp ../data/natural_earth_vector/10m_cultural/ne_10m_populated_places.shp

ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM tmp ORDER BY POP_MAX DESC LIMIT '15'" -dialect SQLITE ./places.shp ./tmp.shp
rm ./tmp.*
```

I tried to merge them via :

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrc 1 52 7 49 \
        -sql "SELECT * FROM ne_10m_populated_places ORDER BY POP_MAX DESC LIMIT '15'" -dialect SQLITE \
        ./places.shp ../data/natural_earth_vector/10m_cultural/ne_10m_populated_places.shp
```

but it fails. I suspect the `FROM ne_10m_populated_places` part to fails on the clipped data.

**How could I do this in a single command ?**

Comment: Didn't found a way! Maybe it's not possible to chain.

Comment: I undestand that you want to select top populated cities from the clipped area? How about switching -clipsrc to sql's WHERE ST_Intersect?

Comment: Yes indeed, i am looking for such way if chaining clip => sql select is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select top populated cites in given extent you can use ogr2ogr's option `-spat`: spatial query extents.

Only features whose geometry intersects the extents will be selected.

Try:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM ne_10m_populated_places ORDER BY POP_MAX DESC LIMIT '15'" -dialect SQLITE -spat 1 49 7 52 ./places.shp ../data/natural_earth_vector/10m_cultural/ne_10m_populated_places.shp
```

Comment: Top populated places from target area? (From my mobile) if so => yes!

Comment: Working and adopted!!!